# MS Access: query criteria in subform of a navigation form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, acc

I have set of cascading combo boxes that query a table and uses criteria this will function without an issue when it's not in a navigation subform.  So I have tried to update the query to go through the navigation form and it is not working.

IntelliSense works up to
 [Forms]![frmNavigation]![btnNavigationButton]

Then when trying to select FORM it does not come up so I manually enter the reset.

.[FORM]![cboValue]

I have also attempted other syntaxes like the ones mentioned in this link:https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/599404-referring-items-sub-form

Also, have rebuilt the navigation form from scratch and have run a compact & repair.

I have spent hours searching and trying the different solutions on here and google and the standard ones I have been coming up.

for some reason, the [btnNavigationButton] does not have .Form property is am not sure if there some property that needs to be manually set to get this to work

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think the issue might have been since I was using NavigationLinkSource.  So i am trying to use Subform wizard and see if the relationships will work that way.

Comment: Is btnNavigationButton name of the navigation control? Access usually names it `NavigationSubform`. Don't reference the buttons (tabs).

Comment: Edit question to show the SQL of dependent combobox. All comboboxes are on same form? Probably don't need full path. `SELECT City FROM Cities WHERE State=[cboState];`

Comment: btnNavigationButton is the tab button name on the navigation form I will take a look at NavigationSubform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user that left a comment answered the question for me.  I was setting it to the wrong controller i was selecting the button controller and needed to select `NavigationSubform` controller appreciate the everyone feedback.